# Java instantiate class of parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Here's what I have:

```
class Class1 <T>
{
     public void foo()
   {
      ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType)getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
      Class<T> type = (Class<T>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
      System.out.println(type);
   }
}

class Class2 <G>
{
    public Class2 ()
    {
        Class1<G> class1 = new Class1<G>();
    }
}
```

But when I call class1.foo(), I get the superclass and not the parameter.

If I do

```
Class1<String> class1 = new Class1<String>();
```

and then call class1.foo() inside Class1, I get String.

How can I fix to instantiate Class1 with the generic type of Class2?

Comment: How did you manage to get `String` for Class1 case?

Comment: "and then call class1.foo() inside Class1, I get String." No, you will hit a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot.  At runtime, `Class2` doesn't know what its generic type argument is.